# Question about surjectivity of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

Why is the following linear map not surjective?

$T \in \mathcal L (\mathcal P(\mathbb R),\mathcal P(\mathbb R)): (Tp)(x) = x^2p(x)$

According to my book, $1$ is not in the range of $T$. Can't you get $1$ for $p(x) = x$ and $x = 1$, so $x^2p(x) = 1^2\cdot1$? What am I misunderstanding?

Thank you.

Comment: Please define your terms.  What is $P(\mathbb R)$ ?  What is $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @lulu Excuse me. I fixed it, it's supposed to be both $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$. They are the polynomials over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ok.  Well, the polynomial $p(x)=1$ is not divisible by $x^2$ so it isn't in the image of $T$.  Neither is the polynomial $p(x)=x$.

Comment: No no. I understand your problem. But you are confusing the polynomial 1 within assign to $x$ the value 1. The polynomial 1 is the polynomial such that $1(x)=x$ for all $x$. Even when $x=3$, $1(x)=1$. You cannot get this polynomial if you multiply by $x^2$, since the independent term is missed.

Comment: Note that every polynomial $q(x)$ in the image of $T$ satisfies $q(0)=0$.  That's another way to see that $T$ can't be surjective.

Comment: Alright I get it now I think, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

For p(x) = x, you get T(p(x)) = x^2, and this is not constant polynomial q(x) = 1, what you are getting is the value 1 at x = 1.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. I thought the $1$ that was supposed to be in the range of $T$ was the value 1 but they indeed mean the constant polynomial. Thanks!